# hello, when i open my terminal in ubuntu i found this erreur

Tags: python

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mohamed/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/stevedore/_cache.py", line 28, in <module>
    import importlib.metadata as importlib_metadata
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'importlib.metadata'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/mohamed/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/virtualenvwrapper/hook_loader.py", line 16, in <module>
    from stevedore import ExtensionManager
  File "/home/mohamed/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/stevedore/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .extension import ExtensionManager
  File "/home/mohamed/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/stevedore/extension.py", line 19, in <module>
    from . import _cache
  File "/home/mohamed/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/stevedore/_cache.py", line 31, in <module>
    import importlib_metadata
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'importlib_metadata'
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3 and that PATH is
set properly.
```

Comment: A bit more explanation of the problem is necessary.

Also please use proper spelling in your question. And remove the "hello"

Comment: maybe try `from importlib import metadata as importlib_metadata`

Answer (score 4):

You are using python 3.6. In python versions before 3.8, importlib.metadata is stored under importlib_metadata.

To import this then, you need to do

```py
import importlib_metadata
```